# Why isn't PuLP returning solutions to my integer linear programming model in Python?

Tags: python, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

Python's PuLP module can't solve my integer linear programming model.
However, I'm convinced there are integer solutions to my problem.
I definitely don't understand why PuLP isn't returning any solutions.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Here's my code:

```py
from pulp import *
import networkx as nx


def solver(k,G,safe,Qmax):

    n = len(G)
    mu = [1.0/n]*n #Temporary

    unsafe = [i for i in range(n) if not i in safe]

    maet = LpProblem("ResolveMAET", LpMinimize)

    q = {i:(str(i)) for i in G}
    p = {(i,j):(str(i)+","+str(j)) for i in unsafe for j in G.neighbors(i)}

    q_var = LpVariable.dicts("q",[qi for qi in q.values()],lowBound = 0, upBound = Qmax, cat = 'Continuous')
    p_var = LpVariable.dicts("p",[pij for pij in p.values()],lowBound = 0, upBound= 1, cat = 'Binary')

    ### Objective function
    maet += lpSum([ mu[i] * q_var[q[i]] for i in q])

    ### Constraints

    #Markov Chain (Constraint n°1)
    for i in unsafe:
        Mij = 1.0 / G.degree(i) #Temporary

        maet += q_var[q[i]] - lpSum([Mij*q_var[q[j]] for j in G.neighbors(i)]) + Qmax * lpSum([p_var[p[i,j]] for j in G.neighbors(i)]) >= lpSum([ Mij*G[i][j]["weight"] for j in G.neighbors(i) ])

    #Sign (Constraint n°2)
    for i,j in p:

        maet += q_var[q[i]] - q_var[q[j]] - Qmax*p_var[p[i,j]] >= G[i][j]["weight"] - Qmax

    #At Most One Sign Per Node (Constraint n°3)
    for i in unsafe:
        maet += lpSum([p_var[p[i,j]] for j in G.neighbors(i)]) <= 1

    #At Most k Signs (Constraint n°4)
    maet += lpSum([p_var[p[i,j]] for i,j in p]) <= k

    #Shelter (Constraint n°5)
    for i in safe:
        maet += q_var[q[i]] <= 0 #=0 car q_var[q[i]] >= 0

    ### Résolution
    maet.solve()

    return [(i,j) for i,j in p if p_var[p[i,j]].varValue==1]


######################

v= 4.0 #km/h

# Graph initialization
G = nx.Graph()

file_density = open("densite.txt", 'r', encoding="UTF8")
mu = dict()

id_to_pos = {}
pos_to_id = {}

id = 0

for l in file_density:
    data = l.split(",")
    for i in range(0,len(data),3):
        vertex = (float(data[i][1:]),float(data[i+1]))
        number = int(data[i+2][6:])

        id_to_pos[id] = vertex
        pos_to_id[vertex] = id
        mu[id] = number

        id+=1

file_density.close()


# Ajout des noeuds
G.add_nodes_from([i for i in range(id)])


file_graph = open("graph.txt", 'r', encoding="UTF8")
file_graph.readline()

for l in file_graph:
    data = l.split(" ")
    weight = float(data[1])
    extremity1 = pos_to_id[(float(data[2].split(",")[0][1:]),float(data[2].split(",")[1][0:]))]
    extremity2 = pos_to_id[(float(data[3].split(",")[0][1:]),float(data[3].split(",")[1][0:]))]

    G.add_edge(extremity1, extremity2, weight=v*weight)

file_graph.close()


from random import randint

safe = [randint(0,len(G)) for i in range(10)]

print(solver(100,G,safe,60000.0))
```

I've checked the variables and coefficients, and they all seem correct.
I think the problem comes from the Qmax constant.

Remark : This constant transforms conditional constraints into linear constraints.
For example, the constraint $q_i = t_{i,j} + q_j$ if $p_{i,j} = 1$ is replaced by the linear constraint $q_i \geq t_{i,j} + q_j - Q_{max} (1-p_{i,j})$ (contraint n°2)

Comment: What does the solver status say after the solve?  Also, your error is not reproducible without the data file.  Can you edit your post and include enough of your data file to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Also, if you are asking for help debugging....  it is much more likely you'll get help if you take the time to comment some of your variables and explain in a bit more detail the objective.  What are `k` and `safe`?  What do you intend for the model to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made up a small set of fake data and ran this and it returns `optimal` with some kind of solution.  **I have no idea what it is doing** or what the meaning of the result is, but the model appears to be generating integer results.  Perhaps this will help you in troubleshooting.

Also note that I dropped in a print statement to print out the model, which you should be doing for troubleshooting.

##### Code:

```
from pulp import *
import networkx as nx


def solver(k,G,safe,Qmax):

    n = len(G)
    mu = [1.0/n]*n #Temporary

    unsafe = [i for i in range(n) if not i in safe]

    maet = LpProblem("ResolveMAET", LpMinimize)

    q = {i:(str(i)) for i in G}
    p = {(i,j):(str(i)+","+str(j)) for i in unsafe for j in G.neighbors(i)}

    q_var = LpVariable.dicts("q",[qi for qi in q.values()],lowBound = 0, upBound = Qmax, cat = 'Continuous')
    p_var = LpVariable.dicts("p",[pij for pij in p.values()],lowBound = 0, upBound= 1, cat = 'Binary')

    ### Objective function
    maet += lpSum([ mu[i] * q_var[q[i]] for i in q])

    ### Constraints

    #Markov Chain (Constraint n°1)
    for i in unsafe:
        Mij = 1.0 / G.degree(i) #Temporary

        maet += q_var[q[i]] - lpSum([Mij*q_var[q[j]] for j in G.neighbors(i)]) + Qmax * lpSum([p_var[p[i,j]] for j in G.neighbors(i)]) >= lpSum([ Mij*G[i][j]["weight"] for j in G.neighbors(i) ])

    #Sign (Constraint n°2)
    for i,j in p:

        maet += q_var[q[i]] - q_var[q[j]] - Qmax*p_var[p[i,j]] >= G[i][j]["weight"] - Qmax

    #At Most One Sign Per Node (Constraint n°3)
    for i in unsafe:
        maet += lpSum([p_var[p[i,j]] for j in G.neighbors(i)]) <= 1

    #At Most k Signs (Constraint n°4)
    maet += lpSum([p_var[p[i,j]] for i,j in p]) <= k

    #Shelter (Constraint n°5)
    for i in safe:
        maet += q_var[q[i]] <= 0 #=0 car q_var[q[i]] >= 0

    ### Résolution
    print(maet)  # <-- take a look at the math and make sure it matches your math model before moving to larger dataset
    maet.solve()

    return [(i,j) for i,j in p if p_var[p[i,j]].varValue==1]


######################

v= 4.0 #km/h

# file_density = open("densite.txt", 'r', encoding="UTF8")
# mu = dict()

# id_to_pos = {}
# pos_to_id = {}

# id = 0

# for l in file_density:
#     data = l.split(",")
#     for i in range(0,len(data),3):
#         vertex = (float(data[i][1:]),float(data[i+1]))
#         number = int(data[i+2][6:])

#         id_to_pos[id] = vertex
#         pos_to_id[vertex] = id
#         mu[id] = number

#         id+=1

# file_density.close()


# # Ajout des noeuds
# G.add_nodes_from([i for i in range(id)])


# file_graph = open("graph.txt", 'r', encoding="UTF8")
# file_graph.readline()

# for l in file_graph:
#     data = l.split(" ")
#     weight = float(data[1])
#     extremity1 = pos_to_id[(float(data[2].split(",")[0][1:]),float(data[2].split(",")[1][0:]))]
#     extremity2 = pos_to_id[(float(data[3].split(",")[0][1:]),float(data[3].split(",")[1][0:]))]

#     G.add_edge(extremity1, extremity2, weight=v*weight)

# file_graph.close()

connections = [
    (0, 1, 0.5),
    (1, 2, 2.0),
    (1, 3, 2.5),
    (2, 4, 3.0),
    (3, 5, 6.4),
    (4, 5, 1.0),]

# Graph initialization
G = nx.Graph()

for c in connections:
    G.add_edge(c[0], c[1], weight=c[2])
print(list(G.neighbors(1)))


from random import randint

# safe = [randint(0,len(G)) for i in range(10)]
safe = [2, ]

print(solver(3,G,safe,60.0))
```